# getting an unknown bug in my java program

Tags: java

I had made a Java program - this program  will randomly choose 3 numbers from 0 to 7 and we have to guess what they are. To hit all of the numbers, I want to validate input.  If the user enters a number greater than 7, it would ask number for it again, while ignoring the previously entered number by the user.

The code is successfully compiling, but when I run it and choose a number greater than 7, it does not prompt the user for a new number. What could be causing the error?  How can I fix it?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class GameHelper {
    public String getUserInput(String prompt) {
        String inputLine = null;
        System.out.print(prompt + " ");
        try {
            BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            inputLine = is.readLine();
            if(inputLine.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException: " + e);
        }
        return inputLine;
    }
}

class DotGame {
    private int PlayerGuess;
    private int NumberOfGuesses = 0;
    private int[] SelectedNumbers;
    private int NumberOfHits = 0;

    public void setPlayerGuess(String PlayerGuess1) {
        int PlayerGuess2 = Integer.parseInt(PlayerGuess1);
        if(PlayerGuess2 < 8) {
            PlayerGuess = PlayerGuess2;
        } else {
            System.out.println("enter number smaller than 8 ");
        }
    }

    public int getPlayerGuess() {
        return PlayerGuess;
    }

    public void setSelectedNumbers(int[] selected) {
        int totalArrayValue = selected[0] + selected[1] + selected[2];
        if(totalArrayValue < 21) {
            SelectedNumbers = selected;
        } else {
            System.out.println("values in array are more than they should be ");
        }
    }

    public String checkPlayerResult() {
        boolean big = true;
        NumberOfGuesses++;
        String result = "miss";

        for(int number : SelectedNumbers) {
            if(PlayerGuess == number) {
                result = "hit";
                NumberOfHits++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(NumberOfHits == SelectedNumbers.length) {
            result = "killed";
        }
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    }

    public void GameScore() {
        int Score = NumberOfHits * 100 / NumberOfGuesses;

        System.out.println("Number of hits " + NumberOfHits);
        System.out.println("Number of guesses " + NumberOfGuesses);
        System.out.println("you scored " + Score);
    }
}

public class DotGameTester2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GameHelper helper = new GameHelper();
        int random = (int) (Math.random() * 7);
        int random1 = (int) (Math.random() * 7);
        int random2 = (int) (Math.random() * 7);

        DotGame game = new DotGame();
        int[] selectnumb = { random, random1, random2 };
        boolean isAlive = true;
        int numOfGuesses = 0;
        int test = 0;
        game.setSelectedNumbers(selectnumb);
        while(isAlive == true) {
            do {
                String guess = helper.getUserInput("enter a number ");
                game.setPlayerGuess(guess);
                test = game.getPlayerGuess();
            } while(test > 8);
            String result1 = game.checkPlayerResult();
            numOfGuesses++;
            if(result1 == "killed") {
                isAlive = false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("you took " + numOfGuesses + " to guess");
        game.GameScore();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? In addition, please format your code to make it more readable.

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: `if(result1 == "killed")`. Don't compare Strings using `==`. Use `equals()`.

Comment: this is really bad design. you need to keep your data protected and in the appropriate place. for example you have `numOfGuesses` and `NumberOfGuesses` both of which independently keep track of the number of guesses (improperly i might add). and `NumberOfGuesses` is never used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter `11` as a guess, here's what happens:

```
String guess = helper.getUserInput("enter a number "); // guess == 11
game.setPlayerGuess(guess /* 11 */);
```

Drill into `setPlayerGuess`:

```
if(PlayerGuess2 < 8) {                                  // False, since 11 > 8
    PlayerGuess = PlayerGuess2;                         // skip
} else {                                                // True
    System.out.println("enter number smaller than 8 "); // This line gets executed
}
```

Notice before how you define `private int PlayerGuess;` which defaults `PlayerGuess` to `0`. With that in mind...

```
test = game.getPlayerGuess();
```

This simply returns `PlayerGuess`, which is `0`.

Now, you're running this in a `while` loop, which executes whenever `test > 8`, but right now, `test` is `0`, so the loop terminates.

The fix is to change `setPlayerGuess` to this, so you set the guess every time you enter a number:

```
public void setPlayerGuess(String PlayerGuess1) {
    int PlayerGuess2 = Integer.parseInt(PlayerGuess1);
    PlayerGuess = PlayerGuess2;
    if(PlayerGuess2 >= 8) {
        System.out.println("enter number smaller than 8 ");
    }
}
```

Now when you enter a number greater than `7`, you should be prompted again.

Answer (score 3):

```
while(test > 8)
```

should be

```
while(test >= 8)
```

Moreover when you insert a number greater than 7 you still return previous inserted number to `test`, so you're checking the wrong number.

To fix this I would edit like this:

```
PlayerGuess = PlayerGuess2;

if (PlayerGuess2 < 8) { 
    System.out.println("enter number smaller than 8 ");
}
```

Another solution is to edit the code like this:

```
do {
    game.resetGuess();
    String guess = helper.getUserInput("enter a number ");
    game.setPlayerGuess(guess);
    test = game.getPlayerGuess();
} while (test >= 8);
```

And implementing `PlayerGuess = 8` inside `resetGuess()`

Comment: This is certainly true, but it does not fix the bug in question.

Comment: @DesertIvy Because the question was about more than one bug. Anyway I updated my answer.

Answer (score -2):

your bug: if the user's guess is greater than 7, the `game.setPlayerGuess` does NOT set the numer becoz there is an "if" inside the method. then, you call `game.getPlayerGuess()` and u basically get the **previous** entered valid number.

as mentioned - this is a bad design, anyway!

Comment: someone has downvoted this answer, with no comment why. The interesting thing is, that the ACCEPTED answer is exactly as this one!